# Where did the word "logarithm" come from?

Tags: terminology, logarithms, math-history

Where did the word *logarithm* come from? Any relation to the word *algorithm*?

Comment: A great opportunity to make people aware of our sister site [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) that has a dedicated tag for [etymology questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology?sort=votes&pagesize=30).

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment instead: http://jeff560.tripod.com/l.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no relation between the two words.

*logarithm:* 1610s, Mod.L. logarithmus, coined by Scottish mathematician John Napier (1550-1617), lit. "ratio-number," from Gk. logos "proportion, ratio, word"

*algorithm:* was derived from the **name** of 8th century Persian mathematcian [al-Kwarizmi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu%E1%B8%A5ammad_ibn_M%C5%ABs%C4%81_al-Khw%C4%81rizm%C4%AB).

**Note:** I *think* it's unusual for a term to derive from a person's name, especially in mathematics.  I know words like "bowdlerize" (meaning to edit by removing offensive material) from [Thomas Bowdler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bowdler), or a "spoonerism" (a phrase constructed by exchanging syllables between words, eg "Swell foop") named after [William Spooner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Archibald_Spooner), but in math I believe it's quite rare.  The now-standard lowercase "abelian" is perhaps another example.

Comment: Is there any reason it's called a logarithm and not something else? Now I'm curious.

Comment: This: http://www.pballew.net/arithme1.html seems to agree.

Comment: @Moron You link was very clarifying. Thank you.

Comment: Well, besides abelian, there's Noetherian, Artinian, Gaussian, Riemannian, Jacobian, Laplacian, Lagrangian, Hamiltonian, d'Alembertian, Eulerian, Lorentzian, Dedekind (as in domain), Hilbert (as in scheme), Jacobson (as in ring)...

Comment: I suspect the syntactic similarity between "logarithm" and "algorithm" comes from a Latinisation of the latter name on the part of the scholars who adopted the word.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Note that I was requiring that the word be accepted as "elevated" to lowercase usage in order to sufficiently divorce it from its origin as a proper noun.  Both "algorithm" and (often) "abelian" enjoy this status.

Comment: [That reminds me...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526)

Comment: And also on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44946/why-is-abelian-infrequently-capitalized).

Comment: All is there on Google. Logos to logarithm and whatever.

Answer (score 2):

["There is no relation between the two words."](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37773/880636) feels wrong. The spelling of  *algorithm* was influenced by the Greek **árithmos**, which is the second compound in *logarithm*.

I quote from *Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 16 Left column.

> #### algorithm [13]

> *Algorithm* comes from the name
> of a Persian mathematician, in full Abu Ja far Mohammed ibn-Musa al-Khwarizmi (c. 780–c.
> 850), who lived and taught in Baghdad and
> whose works in translation introduced Arabic
> numerals to the West. The last part of his name
> means literally ‘man from Khwarizm’, a town on
> the borders of Turkmenistan, now called Khiva.
>       The Arabic system of numeration and
> calculation, based on 10, of which he was the
> chief exponent, became known in Arabic by his
> name – *al-khwarizmi*. This was borrowed into
> medieval Latin as *algorismus* (with the Arabic
> *-izmi* transformed into the Latin suffix *-ismus*
> ‘-ism’). In Old French *algorismus* became
> *augorime*, which was the basis of the earliest
> English form of the word, *augrim*. From the 14th
> century onwards, Latin influence gradually led
> to the adoption of the spelling *algorism* in
> English. This remains the standard form of the
> word when referring to the Arabic number
> system; but in the late 17th century an alternative
> version, *algorithm*, arose owing to association
> with Greek *árithmos* ‘number’ (source of
> arithmetic [13]), and this became established
> from the 1930s onwards as the term for a step-by-
> step mathematical procedure, as used in
> computing.
>       *Algol*, the name of a computer programming
> language, was coined in the late 1950s from
> ‘algorithmic language’.

Op cit. p 314 Right column.

> #### logarithm [17]

> Greek *lógos* had a remarkably
> wide spread of meanings, ranging from ‘speech,
> saying’ to ‘reason, reckoning, calculation’, and
> ‘ratio’. The more ‘verbal’ end of its spectrum has
> given English the suffixes *-logue* and *-logy* (as in
> *dialogue, tautology*, etc), while the ‘reasoning’
> component has contributed logic [14] (from the
> Greek derivative *logiké*), *logistic* [17] (from the
> Greek derivative *logistikós* ‘of calculation’), and
> logarithm, coined in the early 17th century by
> the English mathematician John Napier from
> Greek *logós* ‘ratio’ and *arithmós* ‘number’
> (source of English *arithmetic* [13]).

Comment: Very interesting connection. Kudos for not referring to wikipedia.