# What does it mean for a group to be Abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm revising questions on groups for exams, and I still can't quite understand what an Abelian group is. Please help me understand, if anyone could give me a more simple explanation.

Comment: It means $x*y=y*x$ for all $x,y$ in the group. What more do you want to know?

Comment: *Abelian* is the same as *commutative*.

Comment: It's alternatively called "commutative"

Comment: thanks that helps, i always see this term but was never told the definition.

Comment: thank you very much David Richbery.

Comment: finite or infinite groups?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An Abelian group $G$ is a group $G$ such that the order of multiplication doesn't matter. Precisely: an Abelian group is such that $ab = ba$ for all $a,b \in G$.

An example of an Abelian group: the integers.

A non-example: the group $S_3$ of permutations on 3 letters.

Comment: And I find that "abelian" is spelled in lower case even in wikipedia, although it is named after the famous Norwegian mathematician [Niels Henrik Abel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Henrik_Abel), and therefore should be capitalized, to my understanding. Other mathematicians are treated with more respect (e.g. "Gaussian integers", not "gaussian integers", "Lagrangian relaxation", not "lagrangian relaxation").

Comment: Actually, some see it as an even higher honour to have a name associated to an object/definition and not be capitalised, as it means it's truly ingrained in our nomenclature, for instance cartesian plane.

Comment: @DanielRust From my experience, people tend to write "Abel" in lowercase simply because they do not know who Abel is or was, while they do know that Gauss or Lagrange are mathematicians from the past. So, if not being known is an honor, then so it be. (Who are these "some", by the way? :-)). "Cartesian plane" has no lowercase hits on google, at least on the first 2 pages ...

Comment: @mathse [a relevant thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526/mathematical-concepts-named-after-mathematicians-that-have-become-acceptable-to)

Comment: @DanielRust Alright, I see. I would still think that there is a strong(er) statistical relationship between lowercase writing and ignorance than there is between lowercase writing and "ultimate fame". (I'm sure this could be tested.)

Comment: @mathse I honor Abel every day by working in a building named after him ("Niels Henrik Abels hus").

Comment: @FredrikMeyer So why did you spell him in lower case?

Comment: @mathse It is standard terminology. See for example [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44946/why-is-abelian-infrequently-capitalized) mathoverflow post, where they discuss exactly that.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer From the post, I only see that there is a lot of confusion, rather than a standard. But probably this issue is not worthwhile discussing.

Comment: @mathse: I absolutely agree with you - people write Abelian in lower case because they think it's a funny latin word, but do not realize it's the name of a person in the first place. Same with Boolean algebra (worse in German, where people write 'boolsch' instead of Boolesch or Bool'sch, as they have no idea who George Boole was)

Comment: @zane Of course, they think that "abelian" is similar as "commutative", "associative", "invertible" or "diagonalizable". "Boole" is also an excellent example - few students nowadays probably know that there has been a person named "George Boole" - but as you see, the community here seems to agree that the opposite is actually true - that these mathematicians are so famous that their names have become integrable parts of mathematical terminology. (Actually, I wonder then why "Euler" and "Gauss" have not yet made it ...)

Comment: @mathse: agree. Maybe we should add this to the 'relevant thread'?

Comment: Yes, please. (It is also noteworthy to point out that the opposite may happen as well - I knew a few students who always wrote "Eigenvalue" or "Eigen value" because they thought that there did exist a "Prof. Eigen" ...)

Comment: @FredrikMeyer "I honor Abel every day by working in a building named after him" Honouring him by commuting to work is enough for me. \*baddum-tsssh\*

Comment: This comment thread is becoming very off topic. Please move to chat if you plan to discuss this issue further.

Answer (score 6):

Very simply, Abelian groups are ones which satisfy the additional property of commutativity. That means for all elements $x$ and $y$ in the group $G$, $xy = yx$. So the following are Abelian (or commutative) groups:

1. $\langle \mathbb{Z}, + \rangle$ - The group of integers under addition. For $m + n = n + m$ for all integers $m$ and $n$.
2. $\langle \mathbb{Q} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace, \times \rangle$ - The group of non-zero rationals under multiplicaton. for $xy = yx$ for all rational numbers $x$ and $y$.
3. $\langle \mathbb{R}-\lbrace 0\rbrace, \times \rangle$ - The group of non-zero reals under multiplication.
4. $\langle \mathbb{C} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace, \times \rangle$ - The group of non-zero complex numbers under multiplication.
5. $\langle \mathbb{Z}_n, +_n \rangle$ - The group of integers modulo $n$, under addition modulo $n$.
6. Any group of order at most 4.
7. Any cyclic group (and therefore any groups of prime order, because those are necessarily cyclic).
8. Any group in which every non-identity element is of order 2.

The following are groups that are not Abelian:

1. $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ - The general linear group of degree $n$ over reals, namely the group of invertible $n \times n$ matrices with real entries, for $n \ge 2$. Matrix multiplication is (in general) not commutative.
2. $S_n$, the symmetric group of degree $n$, for any $n \ge 3$. This is the group of permutations (bijective functions on a set) of $n$ letters under composition. Composition of functions is not commutative in general.
3. $\langle \mathbb{H} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace, \times \rangle$ - The group of non-zero quaternions under (quaternion) multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

A group is abelian iff its irreducible representation [$\rho$ has dimension 1.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Irreducible_Representations_of_Abelian_Group)

Comment: How is that supposed to be helpful to someone who doesn't even know what "abelian" means?

Comment: Where do you see that in your link? Link doesn't even mention infinite Abelian groups.

Comment: Answers are ***not*** supposed to be only for person asking a question.  Rather, StackExchange is supposed to be a Q&A database/archive for *anyone* in the future on this topic.  Thus, answers that are *way* over the head of the asker are perfectly acceptable here.  I do not understand why people are downvoting this answer.

Comment: Which representation do you refer to when writing "$\rho$"? The link gives a property of (finite) abelian groups, but say that this property characterizes abelian groups. (Does it?)

Comment: @max a linear representation. which property?

Comment: @zane why should it mention infinite abelian groups? feel free to post your answer...

Comment: If you want to use the property “Every irreducible representation of $G$ has dimension $1$” as definition of an abelian group, you better make sure it is equivalent to the definition the rest of the world uses. ;)

Comment: @MaxMorin If you have a counterexample it would be instructive to post it.

Comment: @Zane the link gives necessary and sufficient conditions. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @draks... the link gives a necessary and sufficient condition for a representation of a finite abelian group to be irreducible. It does not define an abelian group (and as such does not answer the question). It is similar to answering the question “What is a horse?” with “A horse has four legs.” It is true that they do, but such an answer does not actually answer the question.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber There is none for finite groups. $|G|$ is the sum of squares of irreducible representations, so if they all have dimension $1$ there are $|G|$ of them, meaning $G$ has $|G|$ conjugacy classes. Thus each conjugacy class is a singleton, so each element of $G$ is in the center of $G$. I'd be very surprised if this is true for infinite groups, tough.

Comment: @MaxMorin let's see, maybe someone else knows: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/818986/19341...