# problem in representation of a finite abelian group

Tags: representation-theory

There is problem, asking, find all in-equivalent representations of an abelian group $G$.

My attempt: Let $f:G \to GL(V)$ a representation, by maschacke theorem $f_g$ is equivalent to direct sum of irreducible representations, $f^{(i)}_g$. Now as $G$ is abelian so, $f^{(i)}_g$'s are of degree one, so in matrix form $f_g$ diagonal matrix, rather exist $T$ such that $Tf_gT^{-1}$ is diagonal for all $g\in G$ where diagonal entries are clearly eigen values of $f_g$. Now what to do ? and what if $G$ is infinite ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex finite dimensional irreducible representation of abelian group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354926/complex-finite-dimensional-irreducible-representation-of-abelian-group)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I would say it is not duplicated only because of the final part of the question,  "what if $G$ is infinite?".

Comment: @math137: Well, I would say that the case where $G$ is infinite is also answered there.

Comment: @DietrichBurde but that is not clear, at least to me

Comment: OK, I see your point. On the other hand, this has been discussed too, already - see the comments [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818986/infinite-abelian-group-counterexample).

Comment: @DietrichBurde now I am convinced, thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nonabelian group with all irreducible representations one-dimensional](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358104/nonabelian-group-with-all-irreducible-representations-one-dimensional)