# Why lower case "a" for "abelian group" and upper case "C" for "Cauchy sequence"?

Tags: terminology

This has been bugging me.

> Why is the lower case letter "a" used to spell "abelian group" when
>   upper case letters are used to spell the terms, "Gaussian Integral",
>   "Cantor set" or "Cauchy sequence"?

Don't know where else to ask.

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: I think it's a matter of convention for Abelian groups, see the preface of the book https://books.google.co.in/books?id=0qL_ujgd2esC&printsec=frontcover&dq=abelian+groups&hl=en&sa=X&ei=511kVcStPIbauQSuqIDYBA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=abelian%20groups&f=false using both uppercase and lowercase A.

Comment: @baharampuri: The author uses simple letters everywhere else it seems.

Comment: This would be more appropriate on http://english.stackexchange.com/ or http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ In any case it's not a math question, and is actually only very tangentially related to math (proper nouns turning into adjectives happen everywhere, not just in math).

Comment: I would say that if you care this not for pure curiosity but for your own writing, then being consistent is the best policy.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Nah.. Answers there would ignore the mathematical context, no?

Comment: I am claiming that there is no mathematical context to ignore. It's purely a question about the English language.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Note [it already has been asked on English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/105866/109750), but as noted there, there is mathematical convention to consider.

Comment: When I know a term is after a person's name, I capitalize it regardless of what others may do, so I capitalize "Abelian" and never has anyone told me to stop. My personal suspicion is that fewer people have heard of Abel than of Gauss, Cantor, or Cauchy and therefore it is more often assumed that "Abelian" is not derived from someone's name and therefore should not be capitalized.

Comment: I had a professor who always capitalized Abelian, out of reverence, I believe. During linear algebra lectures, I often saw him fastidiously placing punctuation on the board, muttering things like "This is a complete sentence, it deserves a period..."

Comment: Adjectival forms in German with small cases.. may be it was how it  began.

Comment: I've just read something quite interesting about Niles Henrik Abel.  Apparently the university where he taught was a great distance from his home, but he enjoyed commuting.

Answer (score 12):

Some references still write here *Abelian group*, and not *abelian group*, e.g., see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelianGroup.html). However, I admit that most texts write it with a lower case. Perhaps "abelian" it is a so common property, that it became a real adjective. Also, Grothendieck's [*anabelian geometry*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anabelian_geometry) is written with a lower case.

The question has been discussed also at MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44946/why-is-abelian-infrequently-capitalized). And the following nice saying can be found at MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526/mathematical-concepts-named-after-mathematicians-that-have-become-acceptable-to):

> You know you've made it as a mathematician when they start using your name in lowercase.

Comment: In fact, I would say it's a duplicate of that MO question.

Comment: @Kimball Or, to stay within MSE, more or less a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526/mathematical-concepts-named-after-mathematicians-that-have-become-acceptable-to. What seems to be new is, that even the negation, i.e. *anabelian* is formed. I did not see *ungaussian*, or *uneuclidean*

Comment: @DietrichBurde *Non-Euclidean* is fairly common.

Comment: @mrp Oh yes, with "non" fairly everthing is fairly common: non-abelian, non-Riemannian, non-Euclidean. But with "un"- or "an" ?

Comment: Who's _Anabel_? ;-)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen "Annabell, ach Annabell" - Reinhard May.

Answer (score 8):

This is an interesting question, in French the rule is clear when you use the proper noun you write with an upper case for instance "Cauchy sequence" is written "suite de Cauchy", "Cantor set" is written "ensemble de Cantor". However when you "adjectify" (It is certainly not the good word, sorry) a proper noun you just stop to put an upper case "abelian  group" is written "groupe abélien" and "Gaussian integral" is written "intégrale gaussienne".

In English http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization the rules seems to be to always put an upper case when the adjective is derived from a proper noun.

So to answer your question, it looks like a gallicism to me.

Comment: Of course the German rules are even stranger: Abel'sche Gruppe, Gauß'sche Glockenkurve, Ohm'sches Gesetz versus abelsche Gruppe, gaußsche Glockenkurve, ohmsches Gesetz

Comment: My language isn't great. So after reading that bit on the wikipedia article it seems writing "abelian" would be *wrong* to the pedantic.

Comment: @Ishfaaq What is your native language then ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sinhalese, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhalese_language and Tamil http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_language. I speak both. Education is mostly in English though. .

Comment: @Ishfaaq So how would you write "abelian group" in, say, Tamil ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I know for a fact that "abelian group" has never been pronounced in Tamil in Sri Lanka - maybe in South India but unlikely. No capitalisation in Tamil. Both words would be directly translated. Reads something like, "*abelian kuzhu*"

Comment: Remember that in English we have a category that doesn’t exist in French: the *proper adjective*. The question then is only one about English; there’s no doubt that a pedant would object to “abelian group”. My upbringing was that the groups take his name uncapitalized, but Abelian varieties take the capital. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

> *This has been bugging me.*

For [bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug)-related problems, please use [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) ;-$)$

---

> *Why lower case “a” for “abelian group” and upper case “C” for “Cauchy sequence” ?*

Because Cauchy is a proper name, whereas abelian is an adjective. If it would have been called “Abel group”, then capitalization would have been mandatory. You can, of course, capitalize the adjective Abelian also, if you so desire, but, as I said, it's not mandatory.

Comment: The first contentious example in the body of the question was "Gaussian" which is also an adjective and is almost always capitalised.

Comment: @Ishfaaq: As I said, it is a matter of convention. You don't have to capitalize such adjectives, but you can, if you so wish.

Comment: @Ishfaaq: Also, notice that Gaussian integrals and abelian groups belong to very distinct mathematical fields, the former being used in calculus and statistics, and the latter in abstract algebra. Mathematicians, as a whole, do not exactly form some sort of monolithic group of people, which is why different standards and conventions arise in different areas of mathematics.

Comment: But I thought "Cauchy" in "Cauchy sequence" was also an adjective.

Comment: @Arkamis: It is a *noun* $($or substantive$)$, acting as an *attribute*. The former is a [part of speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech), the latter is a [grammatical modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier).