# Isomorphic Sylow p-subgroups of two finite abelian groups G and H

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be abelian groups of order $n$. I want to prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $H$ if and only if for every prime $p\mid n$, Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$.

One direction is obvious.

How do I show that the other direction, i.e. if Sylow $p$-groups are isomorphic then Groups are isomorphic.
The goal of this question is to make easier to verify list of finite abelian groups of order $n$ (up to isomorphism).

Comment: Do you know the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups? I assume not, given the goal of the question (and given that the theorem trivializes this question), but in my experience this structure theorem is generally proven or at least mentioned before discussion of the Sylow theorems.

Comment: @Stahl [Why lower case “a” for “abelian group” and upper case “C” for “Cauchy sequence”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299414)

Comment: @user10354138 Somehow I had it in my head that abelian should be capitalized. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can certainly prove a baby version of the structure theorem for finite abelian groups:

**Theorem**: A finite abelian group $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups.

*Proof*: Let $\#G=n=p_1^{n_1}\dots p_r^{n_r}$.  By Euclid/Bezout/..., there exists integers $m_1,\dots,m_r$ such that $n/p_i^{n_i}$ divides $m_i$ and $m_i\equiv 1\pmod{p_i^{n_i}}$.  Then $m_1+m_2+\dots+m_r\equiv 1\pmod{p_i^{n_i}}$ for all $i$ and hence $\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.  By Cauchy, $g^n=1$ for all $g\in G$ so $g^{m_i}$ has $p$-power order, i.e., lies in the Sylow-$p_i$ of $G$, and
$$
g=g^{m_1+m_2+\dots+m_r}=g^{m_1}g^{m_2}\dots g^{m_r}
$$
gives the desired result.  QED.